# Laravel eloquent query where-like

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I try a search bar where I wanna type a price like 3000 and I want to show me a range of prices from 3000-3999 and for the others prices as well, 1000-1999, 2000-2999, etc...

I have this code which shows me only the exact price I type

```
->orWhere('price', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search.'%');
```

How do I have to do this?

Comment: try ```orWhereBetween('price',$request->search,$request->search+999);```

Answer (score 0):

If your request always have something like

1000 2000 3000 ...

You could do something like

```php
->whereBetween('price', [(int)$request->search, (int)$request->search+999])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LIKE` clause looks for specific patterns and usually useful for searching strings. You would be better off using COMPARISON or LOGICAL operators to look for prices between the each range.

```
$lowerLimit = (int)$request->search;
$higherLimit = $lowerLimit + 999;

$query->whereLike('name','LIKE','$%'.$request->name.'%')

      .... Additional Conditions

      ->orWhereBetween('price',[$lowerLimit, $higherLimit]);
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answears solved my problem but I managed to solve it like this

```
->when(is_numeric($request->search), function ($query) {
    $query->orWhereBetween('price', [$request->search, $request->search + 999]);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
->whereBetween('price', [$request->search, $request->search + 999])
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.